# How to access customized object value inside postgresql function?

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to postgresql function, wondering how to we access the value from a customized type inside postgresql?

For example the following example, `BreakoutMatchingsDecrementProps` is the customized type and I'm not able to use `record.communityId` to get the value...

```
CREATE TYPE BreakoutMatchingsDecrementProps AS (
    weekId int,
    communityId varchar,
    timeSlot int,
    groupSize breakoutsize,
    day weekday
);
```

```
create or replace function Test (obj BreakoutMatchingsDecrementProps[])
returns void as
$$
  DECLARE
    record BreakoutMatchingsDecrementProps;
  BEGIN
    FOREACH record IN ARRAY obj LOOP
      update breakout_matching 
      set number_of_registration = number_of_registration - 1
      where week_id = 1
      AND community_id = record.communityId
      AND time_slot = 1
      AND group_size = 'Two'
      AND day = 'Monday'
      AND number_of_registration > 0;
    END
  END
$$
language plpgsql;
```

I'm using Supabase and client side looks like:

```
const { data, error } = await adminClient.rpc(
    "test",
    {
      obj: 
        {
          timeSlot: 1,
          groupSize: "Two",
          day: "Monday",
          communityId: "dshjdfdfak",
          weekId: 1,
        },
      
    }
  );
```

When I changed the `record.communityId` to `"dshjdfdfak"` then it works...

Wondering how do we access customized type object in plpgsql? Thanks!

Comment: The function in your client side code does not match the one you show earlier. They have different names and the client side version has an extra argument.  Edit the question to resolve that.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Sorry, I was using the same naming while testing. Just updated the naming in the question!

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: @Bergi Hi Bergi, I'm not seeing any error...